# Why a template with constexpr function won't evaluate at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

[image]

The constexpr is not evaluated in compile-time as seen in the assembly(CALL instruction), why?

(Using most recent gcc that comes with codeblocks (g++ 4.7.1) with -std=c++11)

Comment: Note an easier way to check it's done at compile time is a static assert.

Comment: I wasn't aware that low reputation prevents you from putting your code into the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` doesn't guarantee compile-time evaluation.  It only guarantees that the `constexpr`, when fed compile-time constant inputs itself resolves to a compile-time constant.

In this case, the compiler chose not to evaluate `getOdd(7)`, even though it could have.  (Note, `getOdd` itself isn't `constexpr` even though `isEven` is.)

The compiler might choose to optimize and inline, for example, you increase your optimization level.  But that has little to do with `constexpr`.

Comment: Yea, like Dietmar wrote, even when I declare getOdd as constexpr too its still not optimizing. When I raised my optimization level it did. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `getOdd()` isn't `constexpr` and the compiler is certainly not required to propagate constant expressions through non-`constexpr` functions. Also, did you compile with optimization enabled? Without optimizations compilers tend to do no otimizations at all.

Answer (score 0):

g++ -O3 will evaluate the expression at compile-time.

Note by the way that a simpler implementation of getOdd would be to return `t | 1`.

Comment: Thanks, good answer but not very detailed as Joe Z's.
And the t | 1, I knew that, but I wanted to test the constexpr mechanism.